# Extract just town/city from flickr api/YQL

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, flickr, yql

I am trying to write a script that returns just a persons village, town or city. I am using the following YQL query, but the results from the [console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) are too specific, they give me the neighbourhood first.

```
select * from flickr.places where lat=51.558418 and lon=-1.781985 and api_key=YOU_FLICKR_API_KEY
```

Here is the results of my query from the console.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2011-10-25T09:35:50Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="123" execution-time="122"><![CDATA[http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.findByLatLon&lat=51.558418&lon=-1.781985]]></url>
        <user-time>124</user-time>
        <service-time>122</service-time>
        <build-version>22535</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results>
        <places accuracy="16" latitude="51.558418" longitude="-1.781985" total="1">
            <place latitude="51.547" longitude="-1.802"
                name="West Leaze, Swindon, England, GB, United Kingdom"
                place_id="sddCvK9SW703gg" place_type="neighbourhood"
                place_type_id="22"
                place_url="/United+Kingdom/England/Swindon/West+Leaze"
                timezone="Europe/London" woeid="39722"/>
        </places>
    </results>
</query>
```

I want to be able to change the place_type_id in the query. I know I could use regex to isolate the info, but I am not sure if that will work for all locations so I would much prefer to have the API just returning my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flickr's `flickr.places.findByLatLon` method, which is being called in the background by your YQL query, accepts an `accuracy` key.

> **`accuracy`** (Optional)
>
> Recorded accuracy level of the location information. World level is 1, Country is ~3, Region ~6, City ~11, Street ~16. Current range is 1-16. The default is 16.

See » [Flickr docs for `flickr.places.FindByLatLon`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.places.findByLatLon.html).

Putting that to use is as simple as providing `accuracy =`*`n`* in your `where` clause. A value of around 10 looks to be about the accuracy that you are looking for, but experiment to see what is best.

```
select * from flickr.places where 
lat=51.558418 and lon=-1.781985 and api_key=API_KEY_HERE
and accuracy=10
```

---

**Aside**

Documentation for the data sources / services being used by YQL tables can generally be obtained by looking at the table description.

```
desc flickr.places
```

This gives lots of information, usually including at least one link to documentation pages. See the `meta` section for the `documentationURL` items.

[image: desc flickr.places]